# How does git branches work on windows? Two files but only shows one file

Tags: git, version-control

I assume git is essentially copying the source file or at least recording the differences. but you can only see the current branch's version on windows and you need to checkout to a different branch to open its version on windows.

So when you have two branches of a source file, you must have two files right? On your hardware? but the windows explorer can only see one of them, the current branch's file.

So is the other file hidden? How do I look at it without using git?

And technically, if I have infinite branches of a file, will that take up all the space and the windows explorer will only see one file with the size of only one? Then how do you know you are not running out of space when making branches?

And say someone who doesn't know how to use git is on my computer and wants to look at my source file with the version that is not on the current branch, how would he go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So when you have two branches of a source file, you must have two files right? On your hardware? but the windows explorer can only see one of them, the current branch's file.

You may be used to systems like Subversion where each branch is in its own directory, but that's now how Git works.

Git tracks lots of information that isn't visible in your working copy, including versions of files from other branches. This information is stored in the `.git/` directory that is (usually) in the root of your repository.

> And technically, if I have infinite branches of a file, will that take up all the space and the windows explorer will only see one file with the size of only one?

Technically you *can't* have infinite branches :-).

The file size shown for each file in your repository will be the size of that file in the active branch. As you add new commits your `.git/` directory will grow in size, but not very quickly. Git is very efficient at storing data.

Branches are cheap. Adding a branch creates a single 40-byte file in the `.git/` directory.

> And say someone who doesn't know how to use git is on my computer and wants to look at my source file with the version that is not on the current branch, how would he go about doing that?

You could change branches for them, or use something like [`git show`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) to retrieve the file and put it somewhere for them.

It would probably be helpful to read [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), at least the [section on branching and merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).